# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hid'

Tags: python-3.x, hid

## BACKGROUND

Attempt to install hidapi on (Intel) **iMac** MacOS Ventura 13.6.1

```
brew install hidapi
```

I am porting over an old python2 script to **python3**.  Snippet:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import hid, sys, time, datetime, mysql.connector, os.path, commands 
h = hid.device()
```

the **commands** module is deprecated (will not work) in Python3

## FAILED TEST

```
user@iMac% python3
```

Python 3.10.8 (v3.10.8:aaaf517424, Oct 11 2022, 10:14:40) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

```
~>>> import hid
```

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hid'

## pip test

```
user@iMac % pip -V
```

pip 23.3.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)

```
user@iMac% pip install hid
```

Requirement already satisfied: hid in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (1.0.5)
user@iMac Downloads % python3
Python 3.10.8 (v3.10.8:aaaf517424, Oct 11 2022, 10:14:40) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

```
>>> import hid
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hid'

## QUESTIONS

1. How to confirm **'hid'** is not deprecated in python3?
   **'commands'** is deprecated in python3
2. If not deprecated: what tests can be performed to determine root cause of ModuleNotFoundError?

## JOHN GORDON TESTS

Terminal:

```
pip show hid

Name: hid
Version: 1.0.5
Summary: ctypes bindings for hidapi
Home-page: https://github.com/apmorton/pyhidapi
Author: Austin Morton
Author-email: amorton@juvsoft.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

Python:

```
import sys; print(sys.path)

['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python310.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
>>>
```

brew's list of python installs?

```
user@iMac % brew list | grep python

python-setuptools
python@3.10
python@3.11
mysql-connector-python
```

user@iMac ~ % `echo "$PATH"`

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/user/Android/platform-tools:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin
```

Comment: Did you try `pip install hid` ?

Comment: @JohnGordon  Yes: added your good suggestion to the post to show same result.

Comment: Sounds like you have two different installations of python on your computer.  Please edit the question to show the output of this command `pip show hid`, and also the output of this python code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: @JohnGordon.   Results appended to question's 'tail'.   Looking forward to your diagnosis / insight.

Comment: Yes, it is as I thought.  The module is installed for Python 3.11 in `/usr/local/lib/python3.11`, but you are using Python 3.10 in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10` to run the code.

Comment: Do you know why you have two different installations of Python?  Is it intentional?

Comment: In any case, the solution is to choose which Python installation you want to use, and adjust your environment so that all of your tools agree on that version.

Comment: @JohnGordon   Thank you for the astute observation.   `brew list | grep -I python` returns python@3.10 and python@3.11.   I think this indicates that for some reason I had installed these via brew.   Does it make sense (i.e. less is more) to remove 3.10 via `brew uninstall  python@3.10`?

Comment: In general I would advise to remove any versions you don't want to use -- **except** for the default version that came preinstalled on your machine.  I don't know enough about macs and brew to know how to tell which version that is, if any.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256424/discussion-between-gatorback-and-john-gordon).

Answer (score 1):

## Initial Answer

According to [PyPI (Python Package Index)](https://pypi.org/project/hid/) the `hid` Python module is not preinstalled and must be installed with pip: `pip install hid`. Pip is usually installed by default on recent versions of Python. You can check by running `pip -V` or, alternatively, `python3 -m pip -V`. If it isn't, see the [installation instructions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/). Once the module is installed, you should have no trouble importing it.

## Updated Answer

Your problem is a python version conflict. Pip is installing packages for python version 3.11 but your code is running with python version 3.10. I'm not sure how to resolve the conflict ATM. I'll update the answer again when I have time. However, there is a quick solution you can use to save yourself some trouble, although I'd still recommend resolving the versions issue.

The following steps will create and activate a virtual environment to manage python dependencies and avoid installing all your dependencies system-wide.

1. Install VirtualEnv: `pip install virtualenv`
2. Create a virtual environment in your project directory: `virtualenv <NAME>`
3. Activate the virtual environment: `source <NAME>/bin/activate`
4. When you're done: `deactivate`

All together:

```bash
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv <NAME>
source <NAME>/bin/activate
```

Let me know how that goes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.   Please see the "pip test" that has been added to the original posting: the commands you suggested were tested.   BTW, PyPI indicates using the "brew install hidapi" command to install.

Comment: Success in virtual environment.   Thank you for the suggestion / quick incremental win.   This is definitely a win.  That being said  I'd like to clean up the non virtual environment and be able to `import hid` there.   Please keep the  venv solution posted.

Comment: Could you run `echo "$PATH"` and add the output to your question?

Comment: Yes, request added to question's "tail".    Why is $PATH in quotes?

Comment: $PATH is in quotes because it is an environment variable that may or may not be valid for passing directly as an argument for `echo`